# Get argument names in String Interpolation in Scala 2.10

Tags: string, scala, scala-2.10, string-interpolation

As of scala 2.10, the following interpolation is possible.

```
val name = "someName"
val interpolated = s"Hello world, my name is $name"
```

Now it is also possible defining custom string interpolations, as you can see in the scala documentation in the "Advanced usage" section here http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html#advanced_usage

Now then, my question is... is there a way to obtain the original string, before interpolation, including any interpolated variable names, from inside the implicit class that is defining the new interpolation for strings?

In other words, i want to be able to define an interpolation x, in such a way that when i call

```
x"My interpolated string has a $name"
```

i can obtain the string exactly as seen above, without replacing the $name part, inside the interpolation.

Edit: on a quick note, the reason i want to do this is because i want to obtain the original string and replace it with another string, an internationalized string, and then replace the variable values.  This is the main reason i want to get the original string with no interpolation performed on it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your usecase? There maybe a better solution than using string interpolation which is a rather specific construct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Scala's string interpolation can handle arbitrary expressions within `${}` it has to *evaluate* the arguments before passing them to the formatting function. Thus, direct access to the variable names is not possible by design. As pointed out by Eugene, it is possible to get the name of a plain variable by using macros. I don't think this is a very scalable solution, though. After all, you'll lose the possibility to evaluate arbitrary expressions. What, for instance, will happen in this case:

```
x"My interpolated string has a ${"Mr. " + name}"
```

You might be able to extract the variable name by using macros but it might get complicated for arbitrary expressions. My suggestions would be: *If the name of your variable should be meaningful within the string interpolation, make it a part of the data structure*. For example, you can do the following:

```
case class NamedValue(variableName: String, value: Any)

val name = NamedValue("name", "Some Name")

x"My interpolated string has a $name"
```

The objects are passed as `Any*` to the `x`. Thus, you now can match for `NamedValue` within `x` and you can do specific things depending on the "variable name", which now is part of your data structure. Instead of storing the variable name explicitly you could also exploit a type hierarchy, for instance:

```
sealed trait InterpolationType
case class InterpolationTypeName(name: String) extends InterpolationType
case class InterpolationTypeDate(date: String) extends InterpolationType

val name = InterpolationTypeName("Someone")
val date = InterpolationTypeDate("2013-02-13")
x"$name is born on $date"
```

Again, within `x` you can match for the `InterpolationType` subtype and handle things according to the type.

Comment: Thanks!  That was an excellent explanation, and you give an elegant alternative.  Will try that out :)

Answer (score 2):

It seems that's not possible. String interpolation seems like a compile feature that compiles the example to:

```
StringContext("My interpolated string has a ").x(name)
```

As you can see the `$name` part is already gone. It became really clear for me when I looked at the source code of `StringContext`: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.0/src/library/scala/StringContext.scala#L1

Answer (score 1):

If you define x as a macro, then you will be able to see the tree of the desugaring produced by the compiler (as shown by @EECOLOR). In that tree, the "name" argument will be seen as Ident(newTermName("name")), so you'll be able to extract a name from there. Be sure to take a look at macro and reflection guides at docs.scala-lang.org to learn how to write macros and work with trees.